# Confusion in Eisenbud's "Commutative Algebra"

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, representation-theory, invariant-theory

I am having difficulty understanding the following sentence, located in section 1.4.1:

> Suppose that $S = k[x_1,\dots,x_r ]$ is a polynomial ring, and that $G$ is represented
> as a group of linear transformations of the vector space of linear
> forms of $S$ -that is, we are given a homomorphism of groups $G\to GL_r(k)$,
> where we regard the latter group as the group of invertible linear transformations
> of the vector space with basis $x_1,\dots,x_r$.

When he writes that $G$ being represented as a group of linear maps of the linear forms of $S$ means a group homomorphism $G\to GL_r(k)$, I don't see how this makes sense. When I saw the words "represented as a group", I thought immediately of a group representation, so a group homomorphism $G\to GL(V)$; in this case it would appear that $V$ is the vector space of linear forms of $S$. But then $GL(V)$ is not isomorphic to $GL_r(k)$ as $V$ is not finite dimensional over $k$. So I don't really understand how the two ideas are equivalent (even if he didn't mean a representation in this sense, I don't see how the notions are the same).

Would anyone mind explaining this? And if somehow this sentence doesn't make sense, should I just interpret "$G$ is represented as a group of linear transformations of the vector space of linear forms of $S$" to mean a group homomorphism $G\to GL_r(k)$ for the rest of the section/book?

Comment: $V$ is finite dimensional of dimension $r$. The two are isomorphic.

Comment: Isn't the vector space of linear forms on $S$ the vector space of linear maps from $S\to k$? If so then as $S$ is infinite dimensional over $k$ isn't it not true that the vector space of linear forms of $S$ is also infinite dimensional? ($S$ is not finite dimensional as for example $k[x]$ has a basis $\{x^{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, right?)

Comment: Sorry, I meant isn't it true that the vector space of linear maps $S\to k$ is infinite dimensional.

Comment: No, a linear form is something like $a_1 x_1 + ... + a_r x_r$, i.e. a degree 1 homogenous polynomial (then there are quadratic forms and so on). In general "form" means "homogenous". I am not sure it would make sense to talk about linear maps from $S$ to $k$, as the only way to do so would be would basically ignore the entire structure of $S$ as a polynomial ring....

Comment: I agree, it's just that I am used to seeing "linear form" mean as I wrote. It seems that he wrote in the introduction that "form" is sometimes used in place of "homogeneous", and I evidently forgot that. If you interpret form to mean that then it seems "linear form" means as you have described.

Comment: For some reason, linear form as linear polynomial takes priority for me... maybe just a bias from my personal interests :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think "linear forms of $S$" <strike>might be a typo, and if it isn't then it</strike> means the homogeneous linear polynomials in $S$ (note that he writes "of" and not "on"). From context it's clear that the intended meaning is that Eisenbud wants to consider a linear action of $G$ on a finite-dimensional vector space $V = \text{span}(x_1, \dots x_n)$ which is then extended to a $k$-algebra action on the symmetric algebra $S(V) \cong k[x_1, \dots x_n]$.

Comment: That clears things up, thank you! EDIT: indeed, it seems that I forgot that he writes "form" to mean "homogeneous".